# Xcode resolving merge tree conflicts

Tags: xcode, git, merge, branch, git-merge

I'm kind of new to xcode and git and I'm trying to merge my branch called SignIn into the master branch. I'm getting all these conflicts & I'm unsure of how to solve them.

I've tried force merging in terminal but it doesn't help either. Xcode lists all these files when it gives me the conflict message...should I be deleting these files from my local branch? I noticed the master branch doesn't have these files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdo44.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change to your master branch, and then use the option "Merge from branch", and select SignIn.

Worked for me.